# Is it appropriate to use a statistical test to compare the distribution of a time series data feature between the train set and the test set?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-transformation, feature-selection

If the data is time series, and the null hypothesis, assuming the feature has the same distribution in both sets, is rejected, would it be valid to perform feature selection or engineering based on this result (e.g., removing the feature or applying a transformation)? Or would it introduce bias and compromise the model's integrity due to decision-making using the test set?